# Insert a JavaScript Variable Into A Dynamically Generated HTML Link/Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I generate my sidebar through JavaScript and HTML. have trouble inserting my JavaScript variable.

I'm trying to insert project ID inside my test onclick function:

```
function loadSidebar(projectID){
    $("#sidebar-load").html( `<ul class='nav flex-column'><li class='nav-item'>
      <a class='nav-link' onclick='test(`+projectID+`);'>Users</a></li></ul>`);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing else to suggest why it isn't working. Could you debug, see what errors you're getting, what the output is etc.?

Comment: Also, you can just use template literals with back ticks: `${projectId}`

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Adding resolutions to questions isn't the right approach here.

Comment: I have tested your code above and it works fine

Comment: Since you're already using a template literal, why aren't you using variable substitution inside it?

Comment: If `projectID` is a string, you need to put quotes around it. `onclick='test("${projectID}")'`